# JQuery Ajax won't send get request, refreshes page instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this section of code is supposed to send a get request to a predefined url(which includes the variables); then refresh the data table on the page.

However, all it does is refresh the page - my server fails to receive a get request for the stated URL. How can get this to work?

```
$(".ajaxAction").on("click",function (event) {
    var ajaxActionUrl = $(this).data("actionUrl");
    var ajaxActionQuery = $.get({type:"GET", url:ajaxActionUrl, success:function () {
        order_table.ajax.url(ajaxTableUrl).load();
    }});
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

edit : My HTML is actually a Jinja template, my JS file is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){main()})

function main(){
    ajaxTableUrl = $('#initial_table').data("tableLinkedTo")
    $(".container").hide();
    $("#OrderUI").show();
    $("#order_button").parent().css("backgroundColor","#f5f5f5");
    $("#initial_table").parent().css("backgroundColor","yellow");
    $(".menu-tab").on("click",function(){
        $("li.hnav").removeAttr('style');
        $(this).parent().css("backgroundColor","#f5f5f5");
        $("#kinandonboard").parent().removeAttr('style');
        var linkedto = $(this).data("linkedto");
        $(".container").hide();
        $(linkedto).show()
        }
        );
    $("#kinandonboard").on("click",function(){
        $("#order_button").parent().css("backgroundColor","#f5f5f5");
    }
    );
    var order_table = $('#order_table').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,
        ajax : ajaxTableUrl,
        'bSort': false,
        "columns" : [{"data": "orderId"},
                     {"data": "companyName"},
                     {"data": "customerOrderRef"},
                     {"data": "orderPaid"},
                     {"data": "orderPrice"},
                     {"data": "orderDate"},
                     {"data": "requiredDate"},
                     {"data": "orderQuantity"},
                     {"data": "orderStage"},
                     {"data": "orderActions"},],
        "columnDefs": order_table_cols,
        "scrollY":        "200px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "info":           true,
        "paging":         false,
        "searching": false
        }) ;
    $(".order-table-button").on("click",function(){
        $("li.vnav").removeAttr('style');
        $(this).parent().css("backgroundColor","yellow");
        ajaxTableUrl = $(this).data("tableLinkedTo");
        order_table.ajax.url(ajaxTableUrl).load()
        });
    $(".ajaxAction").on("click",function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var ajaxActionUrl = $(this).data("actionUrl");
        var ajaxActionQuery = $.get({type:"GET", url:ajaxActionUrl, success:function () {
            order_table.ajax.url(ajaxTableUrl).load();
        }});
    })
}
```

Comment: move the prevent default up to the first line in the on function

Comment: what is ajaxTableUrl?

Comment: @JordanHendrix Tried that, didn't make a difference :(

Comment: @user2181397 It's the url that the Jquery datables plugin uses to get json from my server.

Comment: My guess is the click event is not actually attached to anything

Comment: if you look at the network tab in your dev tools do you see the request ? it's possible that the server does not receive it because of caching

Comment: My two cents either there are multiple button with same class and if button type is submit. then add event.preventDefault () at the top like this $(".ajaxAction").on("click",function (event) {
 event.preventDefault();
   // rest of code
   
})

Comment: @user2181397 There are multiple buttons of the same class. How does this effect the program? Also, I've tried what you've suggested, no improvement :(

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with  `order_table.ajax.url(ajaxTableUrl).load();` but we cannot tell what error since you didn't post codes for that.
That line will break your code, and therefor, `event.preventDefault();` cannot be executed, result in form submission which shows as page refresh.
Change it to:

```
$(".ajaxAction").on("click",function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var ajaxActionUrl = $(this).data("actionUrl");
    var ajaxActionQuery = $.get({type:"GET", url:ajaxActionUrl, success:function () {
        order_table.ajax.url(ajaxTableUrl).load();
    }});
})
```

so that page refresh stop, and you can see what is error for order_table in Error log console of browser.

Comment: Did that, did not make an improvement.

Comment: then there is an error completely somewhere else that blocking this piece of javascript from running. press F12 in google chrome and check console to see where that error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide more information. Based on this tiny code snippet it is hard to have the overall view what is wrong. Ideally attach also the relevant HTML code for this click listener.

The most common problems related to this issue are:

1. jQuery is not properly loaded, check browser console for errors.
2. The click listener is not triggering and the `even.preventDefault` is not called at all. Check whether the class on which you are listening is correct or whether you are not listening on elements which you were loaded dynamically. Maybe try to add one `console.log('click')` at the beginning of you click event function. If nothing will be logged in the console, you will know where to search.

**EDIT**

Based on the code you provided it seems like that the *data table* loads the data over AJAX (as I described in point **2**). Try to change your code to:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".ajaxAction", function (event) {
    var ajaxActionUrl = $(this).data("actionUrl");
    var ajaxActionQuery = $.get({type:"GET", url:ajaxActionUrl, success:function () {
        order_table.ajax.url(ajaxTableUrl).load();
    }});
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: This is not an answer you could have write it in comment section

Comment: @Kinando I updated the comment based on the code you shared, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am betting you are trying to attach the click event to a dynamic element so it is not there. So you need to change your click to use event delegation.

```
$(".ajaxAction").on("click",function (event) {
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", ".ajaxAction" ,function (event) {
```